# 'Renderer is declared here' error when trying to upgrade from Angular Version 8.X to any newer version

Tags: node.js, angular, node-modules, package.json

I'm getting a Renderer error when trying to upgrade from Angular 8.X to any higher version. I've tried 9.X and 15-17.X. I don't think just changing the file in the node_modules will work, so is there something that I'm missing or is deprecated? I've tried following the guide here: https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=8.0-15.0 and running `npm audit fix` and `npm update --force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` but I can't seem to get past this error.

Thanks!

[image: Renderer error when upgrading from Angular 8.X]

My package.json:

```
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve -o",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.13",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "3.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.2.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "7.5.4",
    "angular-plotly.js": "1.4.2",
    "bn-ng-idle": "0.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "core-js": "2.6.9",
    "file-saver": "2.0.2",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "4.5.0",
    "ng2-charts": "2.2.3",
    "ng2-search-filter": "0.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "3.3.0",
    "ngx-chips": "2.0.2",
    "ngx-nestable": "0.9.4",
    "ngx-quill": "8.0.0",
    "plotly.js": "1.50.1",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "tslib": "1.14.1",
    "xlsx": "0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.901.15",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.15",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.13",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.1.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "8.9.4",
    "angular-file": "1.2.2",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.8.3",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "2.2.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Renderer` is [deprecated](https://medium.com/wevalue-expertise/migrating-to-angular-9-tales-of-a-piece-of-cake-7bb8472acc9c) please do a global search for Renderer import and upgrade it to use [`Renderer2`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to solve this issue.

[Online resource supporting deprecation](https://angular.jp/guide/migration-renderer)